# How cmd get arguments list

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments

I have a file `a.cmd`. Path to the file is `C:\Program Files\a\a.cmd` and `C:\Program Files\a` is in `PATH` environment variable.
When I invoke `a.cmd` from PowerShell (v. 7.2) I see that a process with the following command line is created:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files\a\a.cmd""
```

I wonder what the quotes add (OS, PowerShell or something else) and how cmd.exe handles the arguments list. When I replace cmd.exe with a custom .NET program (eg. by changing `COMSPEC` env variable) I see following command line args (from the cmd.exe replacement perspective):

```
arg 0: /c
arg 1: C:\Program
arg 2: Files\a\a.cmd
```

and whole command line is (`System.Environment.CommandLine`):

```
replaced.exe /c C:\Program Files\a\a.cmd
```

and it make sense to me.

As I know an OS parses a command line and passes it to a process. How does cmd.exe handle these arguments and how can cmd.exe open proper file?

Answer (score 1):

**what the quotes add:** double-quotes in CMD can [sometimes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) be escaped by doubling them to `""`. In this case, CMD just treats them as one double-quote. The second one is there in case the path was not quoted by the launching program.

**how cmd.exe handles the arguments list:** There's a lot of legacy answers to that, but in this case:

- Powershell launches the default program for `.cmd` files: `cmd.exe`
- And windows registry entries determine which/how arguments are passed to default programs:

```
Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\cmdfile\shell\runas\command

(default)    : C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /C "%1" %*
```

Which spells out:

1. launch `cmd.exe` with the `/C` parameter,
2. then the first argument `%1` in quotes (also why you see double-double-quotes in the process cmdline)
3. then the remaining args `%*` (space-delimited)

So powershell (or any program) can also pass more args to a .cmd script like `a.cmd arg1 arg2`

Comment: Not sure are you right. I changed COMSPEC variable to e.g. `replaced.exe` and I see PowerShell runs `"replaced.exe" /c ""C:\Program Files\a\a.cmd""` (spotted in Process Monitor) not the command from registry.

Comment: @kkj yeah the registry stuff might not apply in win 10 since default program registrations aren't handled there anymore. There might be some old OS hook to add `/C` or redirect cmd based on comspec when running cmd-related commands (remember NT `cmd.exe` is 30 years old now), but the idea is the same.

Comment: @kkj the command you used in the question, `replaced.exe /c C:\Program Files\a\a.cmd`, did not have quotes around the path, so it was treated as two arguments because of the space. The OS handles parsing `a.cmd` to `"C:\Program Files\a\a.cmd"` with quotes

Comment: @io-oi No, it is simple program just for debug arguments and whole command line. You can use pwsh.exe or other and the result will be the same.